# The all-caps title check is fooled by titles without letters

Tags: bug, title, quality-filter

This might just be an edge case, but the all-caps checker for the titles isn't 100% accurate. Assuming `title` is the variable for the title, it seems to check

```
title === title.toUpperCase();
```

which is not that accurate of a checker as I have found out by having my cat hold down her paw on the 2 key. This was what I saw
[image]

While "2222222..." is obviously not a good question, I feel as if there are possible other edge cases being ignored by using this method of checking. I propose the check be more along the lines of

```
title === title.toUpperCase() && title !== title.toLowerCase();
```

This would better cover edgecases.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get that prompt even when I enter a bunch of 2s, or even when I type all-caps words into the title. I also discovered that it's possible to enter the 2s without a cat.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Did you try here on Meta, or on Main? I tried both, and Main gave the warning while Meta didn't.

Comment: @Kendra I tried both too, and no warning on either. Were you using a cat?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Interesting on both accounts. I'm more interested as to how you managed to spam 2's without a cat.

Comment: This might be a case of anti-feline discrimination on SO instead of a poorly done checking system.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No, no cat. My cat currently has another appointment, so I couldn't test with him. Perhaps it's rep based? (Though I would imagine 4k rep would be enough not to trigger the warning...) It clearly isn't feline based, unless I'm just incredibly cat like.

Comment: @Kendra Are you by chance, Maureen Ponderosa? Because I think you would count as a cat at that point. (But on a serious note, I'm very confused as to how this is reproducible by some but not all).

Comment: I am indeed not Maureen Ponderosa, though I have on numerous occasions been compared to a cat. I may still count. If a decidedly, 100% non-cat user can reproduce it, I'm back to assuming rep based depending on their rep. (If they have more than Don't Panic, then I'm just flipping a table and walking away.)

Comment: @EliSadoff My chiwawa can confirm that Main gives a warning and Meta doesn't. He's a little perturbed that you haven't considered using a dog to spam.

Comment: @Kendra Ready to flip a table and walk away? (Also zer00ne, my dog is too big to walk on my keyboard. I do love him though).

Comment: oH, i FIGURED IT OUT. I just hadn't left the title field yet. I thought it would pop up as you were typing. So yeah, it's the same for me. I get the warning on main but not on meta.

Comment: @Kendra Your sanity is restored.

Comment: @EliSadoff I wouldn't go that far. I've always been insane, this won't fix it. We now just know that it works for 1) cats 2) dogs 3) humans who may count as cats and 4) regular humans (assuming Don't Panic is a normal human.)

Comment: I don't know about changing this. The proposed change would permit an obviously bad title, and we haven't seen any other examples of edge cases that are being ignored. It seems like this change would make things slightly worse.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - do lizards more closely resemble cats, or dogs?

Comment: @YowE3K I'd say [they look more human than anything](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acCfnwTpdxU).

Comment: This confirms an old suspicion of mine: cats are great at debugging

Comment: What version of cat are you using? I can't seem to replicate.

Comment: BEST Meta thread I've seen in my minimal time here! (Is this comment alright for this?) My cats decided it was time to eat after I showed this to them.

Comment: @dfd It wouldn't have been alright, but thankfully you commented about your cat later on.

Comment: @dfd Comments on meta are _usually_ more lax, though be careful not to get too off-topic with the jokes. This chain mainly revolves around jokes about the cat doing the typing, so it's at least jokes about the topic at hand (kind of) and not likely to be deleted on sight or flagged on sight. (These may be cleaned up in the future, though.) Often times, you'll find jokes about the topic at hand, haikus, or even poems. And the more you stick around, the more likely you are to guess who commented what without looking at the name. ;)

Comment: I can repro this with my cat version , also to see this issue after typing 222 you need to take the focus off the title field to see the issue

Comment: Propose changing this from [tag:bug] to [tag:feature-request] as it's not really a bug.

Comment: Can confirm this also is reproducible with my version of dog.

Comment: @Joe Isn't failing an edge case a bug?

Comment: `1 != 2 || 1 !== 2?`  Seems like a legit Javascript title... :)  btw: my cat was too lazy to type this; I'm her servant for that.

Comment: @EliSadoff It's unclear to me that this is failing, though, particularly given the high level of agreement to BillTheLizard's comment.  Rejecting a title with _no lowercase letters_ seems appropriate.

Comment: @Joe If so, then the warning should be changed. I think it's unfair to call `2222222222222222` an "all-caps" title consider it has no caps.

Comment: @EliSadoff Perhaps, but I still would consider that a feature request.

Comment: @Joe No, because the message says all caps.  It doesn't specifically say that that's what you entered, but it heavily implies that.  And that's wrong.  == bug :)

Comment: @cullub More akin to a "pluralization bug", I'd say, given that there's no affect on the usability of any feature. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/191410

Comment: In addition, I like to see a feature where the warning is reversed for questions tagged as SQL or BASIC. "We noticed your title isn't all caps..."

Comment: We should care about small caaaaaaaaaaaaats and "2cats on my keyboard." With title !== title.toLowerCase(), these titles cannot be accepted.

Answer (score 15):

Your example is a bit contrived. I can't think of a single valid question that *doesn't* have Latin characters in the title.

Some scripts have different casing systems than Latin (or may lack capitals altogether). So asking a question in Arabic with the title "ما هو متوسط سرعة سرعة الطيران من ابتلاع لادن؟" results in the same error:

[image]

But:

1. Stack Overflow is English-only;
2. I can't think of a valid question with a title that lacks a single Latin character;
3. this check is only enabled on Stack Overflow (so it's not a problem on e.g. japanese.SE).

In other words, it seems a bit of a non-issue to me. Yes, the error isn't accurate. But if you're writing a question in Arabic or titled "1231231 2312312312312312" then no amount of messages can help you.

Comment: Fair points, except a pure technical note: Arabic *does* have capitals (it has even 4 cases, not just upper and lower). Perhaps you were thinking of Hebrew? Also: all-lowercase titles should issue a warning as well ...

Comment: @RadLexus Oh, I thought Arabic lacked capitals; not an expert on Arabic obviously :-) At any rate, my point is that doing stuff like this fully correct is tricky, and *probably* not worth the effort. I don't get an error on an all-lowercase title by the way?

Comment: Yes, that is my point. All-lowercase is as low quality as all caps. But - given the diligence of editors and commenters -, the current inclusion of a pre-post all-caps check is an odd choice, when there are so many more ways to write up a plain Very Bad Title. (What, still no solution  for "[Solved](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3asolved)"!?)

Comment: "i++ gives me 0 instead of the expected number" seems valid questions that is all lowercase @RadLexus. At any rate, some missing capital letters is much less annoying than an all-caps SHOUTING title.

Comment: @RadLexus The word "solved" would probably be a bit prone to false positives, though - there are several legitimate questions in there that use "solved" in the title. Unless it was checked only on the edit. What was my point again?

Comment: @RadLexus As an Arabic speaker, I can assure you that Arabic has no capitals, nor any "cases". However, it has **mandatory** typographic ligatures. Letters have different shapes depending on the letters directly before and after them, but these are nothing like uppercase/lowercase.

Comment: @imgx64: as CarpetSmoker is not familiar with Arabic, I was simplifying a bit :) Do the suggested `toUpper` and `toLower` influence initials and terminals as well? Or do they only work on Latin?

Comment: @RadLexus `toUpper` and `toLower` don't have any effect on Arabic letters. The different shapes of an Arabic letter are still the same Unicode codepoint. It's just a matter of how to display them.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the focus into the title field for the warning to pop up.

[image]

---

Anyway, I for one can't think of edge cases where a post with no lowercase letters in the title would be good practice.

### Perhaps we should simply change the message?

[image]

If (like Eli suggested), we check to make sure that `title === title.toUpperCase() && title !== title.toLowerCase();` before displaying the first message, we could also check for `title === title.toUpperCase()` to check if it has no lowercase letters.

Also, I'm pretty sure that the yellow boxes don't prevent you from posting - just the red boxes.  (Like if your title is less than 15 chars)  Although I don't feel like posting a random `22222222222222` question just to find out :)

Comment: I'd simply check whether the title contains alphabetic characters, and if so whether it is all caps. Titles should be English sentences, hence they *must* contain something other than just digits, punctuation, spaces and symbols...

Comment: True, but it seems like that is a separate feature request, as all this is its a warning. (Hence the yellow not red)  -  I'm talking about the *must* part, not the checking. Your idea of checking is probably more efficient, but the SO employees can figure that out imho

Comment: @Bakuriu: Titles generally should not be complete sentences.  For example, "Treatment of titles without letters by the all-caps title checker" is not a complete sentence, it's a fine title for this meta, question, and it's actually better than the one we have.  (Even better would be "Titles without letters trigger the all-caps title check" which is a sentence)  "Sorting XYZ" is a better title than "How can I sort XYZ?"